# Backslash breaks string interpolation in ruby

Tags: ruby, string, escaping, string-interpolation

I'd like to end up with the string `"/a_setting/c\blah = something"` where attribute gets evaluated to its value: blah. However, I'm seeing the following behavior where the preceding backslash seems to stop the evaluation of the variable:

`attribute = "blah"

"/a_setting/c\#{attribute} = something"

=> "/a_setting/c\#{attribute} = something"

"/a_setting/c\ #{attribute} = something"

=> "/a_setting/c blah = something"`

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: `"/a_setting/c\blah = something" where attribute gets` What do you mean by "attribute"?

Comment: Ruby thinks you're escaping the interpolation to print it literally. Just concatenate. `"/a_setting/c\" + attribute + "something"`

Comment: @sawa attribute is just a var that needs to be eval'd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the string you want:

```
"/a_setting/c\\#{attribute} = something"
```

You need to escape the backslash by backslash.

- When you do `"\#"`, the `"#"` is escaped, and is interpreted not as an interpolation element, but as the verbatim `"#"`, which in inspection, appears as `"\#"` in front of `{...}` to avoid ambiguity with interpolation.
- When you do `"\ "`, the `" "` is (redundantly) escaped, and is interpreted as the verbatim `" "`.

Comment: thanks but the string I want is has a single backslash after the c: `/a_setting/c\#{attribute} = something`. If I add a backslash to escape the backslash, I end up with two instead of one (`/a_setting/c\\#{attribute} = something` vs `/a_setting/c\#{attribute} = something`

Comment: It is not two backslashes. It is only one. In inspection, a backslash needs to be escaped by another backslash. There is only one (literal) backslash in `"\\"`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what you are pointing at.

But if you are trying to have your attributed evaluated in the string, probably this is what you want

```
"/a_setting/c\\#{attribute} = something"
```

coz by

```
 "/a_setting/c\#{attribute} = something"
```

you are escaping the evaluation by `#{}` by adding the escape character `\`

So interpreter will evaluate `#{}` rather as an expression.

When you add another `\` before the other `\`, the next \ is escaped and evaluated as a normal character.

```
"\#{attribute}" #:=> "\{attribute}
 "\\#{attribute}" #;=> "\blah"
```

Comment: Your suggestion changes `"/a_setting/c\#{attribute} = something"` to `"/a_setting/c\\blah = something"` when what I need is `a_setting/c\blah = something` (a single backslash instead of two)

Comment: Its not two backslash, its an [escape character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) in eval context