# I want to add backslash to a string which is having interpolation

Tags: ruby, string, ruby-on-rails-3

I have to add backslash("\") to a string. My code is as follows

```
     f=10
     path = "My Documents\#{f}"
```

For the above code the result was "My Documents#{f}"

I expect the result should be like "My Documents\10

Please help.

Comment: why are you downvoting?  I clearly mentioned my expectation

Comment: sawa's approach works (though he didn't explain it well). try `puts "My Documents \#{f}"`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17650832/backslash-breaks-string-interpolation-in-ruby this is what you are looking for.

Comment: @MarekLipka its not working.  its returning My Documents #{f}

Comment: @poojaagarwal sorry, I meant `puts "My Documents \\#{f}"`.

Comment: It returns "My Documents \\10"

Comment: @NickKugaevsky it's only representation. What is printed on STDOUT?

Comment: Yes, you right. In STDOUT everything is okay.

Comment: @poojaagarwal you have your answer here.

Comment: what is STDOUT in ruby?

Comment: @poojaagarwal forget STDOUT. What does `puts "My Documents \\#{f}"` print on the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add \ to escape the \ before string interpolation

```
 f=10
 path = "My Documents\\#{f}"
 puts path
 #=> My Documents \10
```

Hope this helps: here is the screenshot
[image]

Comment: Please post screenshots

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you want to make a path on Windows system you should use `File.join`

```
path = File.join('My Documents', f.to_s)
# => My Documents/10, with usual slash
```

This gives you not what you were asking, but this path will work for windows too. At least in your ruby script

Answer (score 0):

To add '\' to your string, you have to escape the special character by using '\' before special character.

    `f=10
    path = "My Documents\\#{f}"
    puts path
    #=> My Documents \10`